# Get element from list of lists

Tags: list, ocaml

i am having troubles getting the mth element of the nth list in a list. I made this function:

```
let pos tabla n m = 
  let lista = (List.nth tabla n) in
  List.nth lista m;;
```

This always return errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks fine to me:

`utop # pos [[1;2];[3]] 1 0;;
- : int = 3`

Is it possible you start counting at 1?

Comment: Yes, his code is correct. That's why I was asking him to be more precise about the error instead of giving an answer.